# Check if list is empty by function

Tags: c++

I have two structures PQCell to be a cell in my linked list. PriorityQueue to contain a pointer to a linked list made up of PQCells. isEmpty is supposed to return true if my list is empty. But cant seem to get it right.

```
struct PQCell
{
    int priority;
    PQCell *next;
};

struct PriorityQueue
{
    PQCell *head = new PQCell;

    PriorityQueue()
    {
      head->next = NULL;
    }
};

bool isEmpty(const PriorityQueue& q)
{
  if(head == NULL)
  {
    return true;
  }

  else
  {
   return false;
  }
}

int main()
{
  PriorityQueue q;
  isEmpty(q);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `bool isEmpty(const PriorityQueue& q)` you actually never use `q` inside the function (Not saying this is the problem, just pointing this out).

Comment: so add isEmpty(q) to main?

Comment: head is undefined in isEmpty. Please provide a working and verifiable example

Comment: I'm trying to get it to work.

Comment: I have head defined in PriorityQueue q and sent as a parameter to isEmpty. Shouldn't that work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
struct PQCell
{
    int priority;
    PQCell *next;
};

struct PriorityQueue
{
    PQCell *head;

    PriorityQueue()
    {
      head = NULL;
    }
};

bool isEmpty(const PriorityQueue& q)
{
  if(q.head == NULL) // I changed the condition so that i checked if the head is NULL
  {
    return true;
  }

  else
  {
   return false;
  }
}

int main() 
{
  PriorityQueue q; 

  if(isEmpty(q))
    cout<<"it is empty";
  else
    cout<<"it is not empty";
  return 0;
}
```

hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of defining the logic for queues, but I find it easier to make isEmpty return true when the head pointer is null, rather than looking at head->next like you have (which to work, would need you to create head node in the constructor, which is wasteful of memory and not needed). Also I would make the the isEmpty a method on PriorityQueue not  a freestanding function.

Answer (score 0):

If the head contains next cell in the queue and that cell's next in return contains another cell down the queue and so on, then when head is nullptr that is when queue is empty, probably:

```
struct PQCell
{
    int priority;
    PQCell *next;
    PQCell(): next(nullptr) {}

};

struct PriorityQueue
{
    PQCell *head;

    void add(PQCell *newcell)
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            head = newcell;
            return;
        }

        PQCell *thiscell = head;
        PQCell *nextcell = thiscell->next;

        if (thiscell->priority < newcell->priority)
        {
            newcell->next = thiscell;
            head = newcell;
            return;
        }

        while (nextcell != nullptr)
        {
            if (newcell->priority > nextcell->priority)
            {
                thiscell->next = newcell;
                newcell->next = nextcell;
                return;
            }

            thiscell = nextcell;
            nextcell = thiscell->next;
        }

        nextcell = newcell;
    }

    PriorityQueue(): head(nullptr){}
    bool isEmpty() {return head == nullptr;}
};



int main()
{
    PriorityQueue q;
    std::cout << "queue is " << (q.isEmpty() ? "" : "not ") << "empty" << std::endl;

    PQCell c1;
    c1.priority = 5;
    q.add(&c1);

    PQCell c2;
    c2.priority = 15;
    q.add(&c2);

    PQCell c3;
    c3.priority = 3;
    q.add(&c3);

    std::cout << "queue is " << (q.isEmpty() ? "" : "not ") << "empty" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "head of the queue priority: " << q.head->priority << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
queue is empty
queue is not empty
head of the queue priority: 15
```